# Segmentation fault around MD5 code

Tags: c, openssl, runtime-error, md5

While I am running this md5 code, it is taking maximum 64 characters length of input at run time. Whenever I am giving more than 64 characters, it is showing

> `Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-fini.c: 205: _dl_fini: Assertion ns != 0 || i == nloaded failed!`

I need to hash nearly 10kb of input (only string). Do I need to change anything in the header file? Can anyone tell me solution please?

**md5.h**

```
#ifndef HEADER_MD5_H
#define HEADER_MD5_H

#include <openssl/e_os2.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#ifdef OPENSSL_NO_MD5
#error MD5 is disabled.
#endif

/*
  * !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  * ! MD5_LONG has to be at least 32 bits wide. If it's wider, then !
  * ! MD5_LONG_LOG2 has to be defined along.                        !
  * !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
*/

#if defined(__LP64__)
#define MD5_LONG unsigned long
#elif defined(OPENSSL_SYS_CRAY) || defined(__ILP64__)
#define MD5_LONG unsigned long
#define MD5_LONG_LOG2 3  
/*
  * _CRAY note. I could declare short, but I have no idea what impact
  * does it have on performance on none-T3E machines. I could declare
  * int, but at least on C90 sizeof(int) can be chosen at compile time.
  *  So I've chosen long...
  *                                      <appro@fy.chalmers.se>
 */
#else
#define MD5_LONG unsigned long   
#endif

#define MD5_CBLOCK      64
#define MD5_LBLOCK      (MD5_CBLOCK/2)
#define MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH 16

typedef struct MD5state_st
    {
    MD5_LONG A,B,C,D;
    MD5_LONG Nl,Nh;
    MD5_LONG data[MD5_LBLOCK];
    unsigned int num;
    } MD5_CTX;

#ifdef OPENSSL_FIPS
int private_MD5_Init(MD5_CTX *c);
#endif
int MD5_Init(MD5_CTX *c);
int MD5_Update(MD5_CTX *c, const void *data, size_t len);
int MD5_Final(unsigned char *md, MD5_CTX *c);
unsigned char *MD5(const unsigned char *d, size_t n, unsigned char *md);
void MD5_Transform(MD5_CTX *c, const unsigned char *b);
#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

**md5.c**

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include "md5.h"

 char *pt(char *, int );
 int main(int argc, char **argv) 
 {
    char *in;
    char *out;
    printf("ENter the string\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",in);
    size_t len;    //unsigned long len;  size_t len; 
    len = printf("len is %d\n",strlen(in));
    out = pt(in, len);
    printf("MD5 is\t: %s\n", out);
    free(out);
    //return 0; 
 }


 char *pt(char *str, int length) 
 {
   int n;
   MD5_CTX c;
   unsigned char digest[16];
   char *output = (char*)malloc(33);

   MD5_Init(&c);

   MD5_Update(&c, str, length);

   MD5_Final(digest, &c);

   for (n = 0; n < 16; ++n)
   {
     sprintf(&output[n*2], "%02x", (unsigned int)digest[n]);
   }

   return output;
}
```

Comment: `char *in;
    char *out;
    printf("ENter the string\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",in);` *in and *out are uninitialized (and they point nowhere)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem 1**

For this statement:

```
scanf("%[^\n]s",in);
```

When I compile it using the `-Wall` flag, I get the warning:

> `warning: 'in' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
>        scanf("%[^\n]s",in);
>        ^`

As you see, `in` is not pointing to any location in your memory, so you first need to allocate some memory either with an array or `malloc()`:

```
char in[500]; //or a higher value
char *out;
printf("Enter the string\n");
scanf("%499[^\n]s", in);
printf("\nin = .%s.\n", in);
```

or

```
char *in;
char *out;
in = malloc(500); //or a higher value
printf("Enter the string\n");
scanf("%499[^\n]s", in);
printf("\nin = .%s.\n", in);
```

**Possible problem 2**

You are assigning the return from `printf()` to the variable `len`.

```
len = printf("len is %d\n",strlen(in));
```

**Return value [`printf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf):**

> *Upon successful return, it returns the number of characters printed (excluding the null byte used to end output to strings).*

Assuming you want the variable `len` to contain the length of the string `in` and not the number of characters printed by `printf("len is %d\n",strlen(in))`, you might want to assign the return from [`strlen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen) first:

```
len = strlen(in);
printf("len is %d\n", len);
```

Comment: in case if i take --> int len; len =strlen(in); printf("Len \n",len); like this, the problem couldn't solve, the problem is inconsistency at taking the input. It is not taking input more than 64 characters.

Comment: `"%[^\n]s"` is an incorrect format string, it should be `"%499[^\n]"`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thanks, my test passed so I ignored it. Do you have a reference?

Comment: but why it is taking max 64 char length of input only......., can you tell me answer please!!!!